# Pass a char pointer array to a function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I have the following code:

```
int main(){
    char **array;
    char a[5];
    int n = 5;

    array = malloc(n *sizeof *array);

    /*Some code to assign array values*/

    test(a, array);

    return 0;
}

int test(char s1, char **s2){
    if(strcmp(s1, s2[0]) != 0)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to pass char and char pointer array to a function, but the above code results in the following errors and warnings:

```
temp.c: In function ‘main’:
temp.c:6:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
temp.c:6:13: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]
temp.c:10:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘test’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
temp.c: At top level:
temp.c:15:5: error: conflicting types for ‘test’
temp.c:15:1: note: an argument type that has a default promotion can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration
temp.c:10:5: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘test’ was here
temp.c: In function ‘test’:
temp.c:16:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcmp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

I'm trying to understand what the problem is.

Comment: `s1` is just a single character. the prototype of `test` should be `int test(char* s1, char **s2)`

Comment: Always include the errors - they are important, and if we can explain them too you then you'll be able to improve future code yourself.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and treat them as errors (Witg gcc, `-Wall --Werror`). It would catch the bug in this case.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you should include the necessary header files. For `strcmp` you need `<string.h>`, for `malloc` `<malloc.h>`. Also you need to at least declare test *before* main. If you do this you'll notice the following error:

```
temp.c: In function ‘test’:
temp.c:20:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/string.h:143:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
```

This indicates that `test()` should have a `char *` as first argument. All in all your code should look like this:

```
#include <string.h>      /* for strcmp */
#include <malloc.h>      /* for malloc */

int test(char*,char**);  /* added declaration */    

int main(){
    char **array;
    char a[5];
    int n = 5;

    array = malloc(sizeof(*array));
    array[0] = malloc(n * sizeof(**array));

    /*Some code to assign array values*/

    test(a, array);

    free(*array); /* free the not longer needed memory */
    free(array);

    return 0;
}

int test(char * s1, char **s2){ /* changed to char* */
    if(strcmp(s1, s2[0]) != 0) /* have a look at the comment after the code */
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

#### Edit

Please notice that [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) works with null-terminated byte strings. If neither `s1` nor `s2` contain a null byte the call in `test` will result in a segmentation fault:

```
[1]    14940 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

Either make sure that both contain a null byte `'\0'`, or use [`strncmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp) and change the signature of `test`:

```
int test(char * s1, char **s2, unsigned count){
    if(strncmp(s1, s2[0], count) != 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

/* don' forget to change the declaration to 
      int test(char*,char**,unsigned)
   and call it with test(a,array,min(sizeof(a),n))
*/
```

Also your allocation of memory is wrong. `array` is a `char**`. You allocate memory for `*array` which is itself a `char*`. You never allocate memory for this specific pointer, you're missing `array[0] = malloc(n*sizeof(**array))`:

```
array = malloc(sizeof(*array));
*array = malloc(n * sizeof(**array));
```

Comment: first answer to have free() in it :)

Comment: @Shark: Thanks, your comment made me aware of all the segmentation faults which were still in the code ^^".

Answer (score 3):

**Error 1**

```
temp.c:6:13: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of 
built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]
```

Did you mean this?

```
array = malloc(n * sizeof(*array));
```

**Error 2**

```
temp.c:15:5: error: conflicting types for ‘test’
temp.c:15:1: note: an argument type that has a default promotion can’t 
             match an empty     parameter name list declaration
temp.c:10:5: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘test’ was here
```

You are passing the address of the first element of an array `a`:

```
 test(a, array);
```

So the function signature should be:

```
int test(char* s1, char** s2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have several problems. The first is that the prototype is wrong. The data type for `a` decays to a char *pointer* when passing to a function, so you need:

```
int test (char* s1, char** s2) { ... }
```

However, even when you fix this, the `test` declaration isn't in scope when you first use it. You should either provide a prototype:

```
int test (char* s1, char** s2);
```

before `main`, or simply move the whole definition (function) to before `main`.

In addition, don't forget to `#include` the `string.h` and `stdlib.h` headers so that the prototypes for `strcmp` and `malloc` are available as well.

Comment: `malloc.h` ? `stdlib.h` is portable.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an array of char to your function, the argument decays to a pointer. Change your function arguments to

```
 int test(char* s1, char **s2);
              ^
              ^
```

and your code should at least compile